# How to copy Spring's component-scan

Tags: spring, annotations

I want to search for some annotations in a Spring based web application, like `@Entity`. Therefore I need the same functionality like Spring involves when the server starts up and it looks for all classes that are annotated with `@Component`. In my case I don't create singleton's, it's just important for me to collect all those classes annotated with `@Entity`.

Is there any possibility to use existing Spring tools for that? I want to search exactly in the same namespace as Spring does for the `@Component` annotations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring's built-in classpath scanning infrastructure (ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner/ ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser) is geared up for registering classes as BeanDefinitions within an Spring appcontext.

If you're just looking to obtain a list of classes annotated with a given annotation (rather than actually register them in Spring as bean definitions) take a look at the [Google Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library.

Reflections allows you to scan your classpath using various filters, including an annotation filter.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");

Set<Class<? extends SomeClassOrInterface>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(SomeClassOrInterface.class);
Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(SomeAnnotation.class);
```

Comment: Dear Andrew, I am now using your suggested Reflections project since it is way more flexible than the spring's annotation parsing. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Sure, look at `parse()` method in `org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser`. This method is called when Spring encounters `<context:component-scan/>` in the XML configuration. Probably You can strip it a bit to better suit your needs, but it should serve as a comprehensive example.

The class You should be particularly interested in is `org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner`. From JavaDoc:

> Candidate classes are detected through configurable type filters. The default filters include classes that are annotated with Spring's @Component, @Repository, @Service, or @Controller stereotype.

BTW if you need less general solution, maybe your persistence provider has some API to fetch all entity classes?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Tomasz. After doing some research I find Andrew's suggestion more flexible, that's why I am using Reflections now

Answer (score 1):

Spring based solution

- Use spring AnnotationTypeFilter and pass Entity.class as annotationType
- using ResourcePatternResolver load all resouces(.class) under given pacakage
- Use SimpleMetadataReaderFactory to get MetadataReader
- for each resource you can call match on AnnotationTypeFilter using MetadataReader
- metadataReader.getAnnotationMetadata().getClassName() will provide FQN of class

**usage**

```
AnnotatedClassFinder entityScanner = new AnnotatedClassFinder(Entity.class);
entityScanner.setPackages(Arrays.asList("org.myapp.domain"));

Collection<Class<?>> entities = entityScanner.findMarkedClassOfType();


public class AnnotatedClassFinder {

    private static final String CLASS_RESOURCE_PATTERN = "**/*.class";

    private List<String> packages;

    private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();

    private final ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = ResourcePatternUtils
            .getResourcePatternResolver(resourceLoader);

    private final MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory = new SimpleMetadataReaderFactory();

    private final TypeFilter annotationFilter;

    public AnnotatedClassFinder(final Class<? extends Annotation> annotationToScanFor) {

        annotationFilter = new AnnotationTypeFilter(annotationToScanFor);
    }

    public Set<Class<?>> findMarkedClassOfType() {

        if (packages == null) {
            return new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        }

        final Set<Class<?>> annotatedClasses = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        try {
            for (final String p : packages) {
                final String packageSearchPath = ResourcePatternResolver.CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX
                        + ClassUtils.convertClassNameToResourcePath(SystemPropertyUtils.resolvePlaceholders(p)) + "/"
                        + CLASS_RESOURCE_PATTERN;

                final Resource[] resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources(packageSearchPath);

                for (final Resource resource : resources) {
                    if (resource.isReadable()) {
                        final MetadataReader metadataReader = this.metadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(resource);

                        if (annotationFilter.match(metadataReader, metadataReaderFactory)) {
                            annotatedClasses.add(Class.forName(metadataReader.getAnnotationMetadata().getClassName()));

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return annotatedClasses;
        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("I/O failure during classpath scanning", ex);
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Class loading failure during classpath scanning", ex);
        }

    }

    public void setPackages(final List<String> packages) {

        this.packages = packages;
    }

}
```

Comment: this solution is modification of AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

Comment: Thanks dasbh for providing an answer that uses the Spring framework only. That was my original desire, but now I don't have any chance to test it, but +1 anyway. Thanks again.